# What is the actual reason why XAML controls are using 'Visibility' type instead of plain 'bool'?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

We all know that XAML UIElements are using property named **Visibility** of type

```
public enum Visibility { Visible, Collapsed }
```

My question is, what is the actual historical(?) reason this property is of type Visibility, instead of just having plain **IsVisible** property of type **bool**?

It would definitely save us lot of time spent on writing/using BoolToVisibilityConverters.

Comment: Actually, there are [three states of `Visibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx), and both of the 'hidden' states have their uses. WinRT (AFAIR) and Silverlight have only two, but still...

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek On Silverlight too.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. True, I've changed the comment to reflect that, thanks for pointing that out. My memory is quite foggy now, but I *think* that WinRT also has only two...

Comment: Also, WPF contains a default [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx). It doesn't work by default, but you don't need to write your own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> instead of just having plain IsVisible property of type bool?

Because there are multiple values **in WPF**, not just two.  There are:

- Visibile
- Collapsed
- Hidden

[Visibility Enumeration - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

> WPF has a Visibility state of Hidden. Silverlight does not support the
>   Hidden Visibility state. If you are migrating XAML UI definitions from
>   WPF XAML, you will have to edit any cases that attempt to set a
>   Visibility to Hidden.

Comment: Well, that's not entirely true. In Silverlight there is only two.

Comment: @It'sNotALie In Silverlight there are two, yes, but Silverlight uses the presentation framework at its core, and is essentially just a lightweight WPF. So the reason Silverlight doesn't use a `bool` is because WPF already had three built into the framework before Silverlight was developed

Comment: Oh, thanks! I'm developing only Windows Phone and Windows 8 apps for some time now and I haven't really seen the third WPF state yet.

Answer (score 1):

Because in WPF, it also has another value. `Hidden`. This is the same as `Collapsed`, but it reserves space for it in the layout.